# Frozen PEX in exterior shower wall

Tags: plumbing, pipe, exterior, pex

The temp dropped to zero last night and the shower head mounted on an exterior wall has no water flow: frozen PEX line. There is no access to this space from above or below. If I use a hair dryer on the ceramic tile under the shower head, could it provide enough warmth to thaw the line? What else can I do to unfreeze the PEX?

Comment: Hair dryer should work, only take three or four weeks.  Bad place for a water line in exterior wall.  Pex pipe is nicer for not cracking/breaking due to frozen water most times, copper line would be cracked/busted.  Need to make an opening in the wall some where to let heat in.  Closer to bottom since heat rises.

Comment: When warm weather comes back, will need to think about changing that shower.  Either have cold air leak near pipes or not enough insulation or heat getting to pipes.  Zero not really that cold, at least in Canada.

Comment: a heat lamp on the wall would be quickest, but still not quick.

Comment: @crip659 I would agree that some may not think zero is that cold but zero C or zero F that would be -17.8 c so it could be quite cold.

Comment: Seeing this is a shower, one way might help is take shower head off and pour hot water down in the pipe carefully, hopefully shower pipe can be turned up or have a hose on it.  Have found that if spilled water does not matter, very hot water pour on pipes will unfreeze them in minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are in an area where the temperature dropping to zero (°F) is unusual.

Crank up the heat in the room, or the whole house. Don't know that I'd bother with a hairdryer - they are noisy and need someone to hold them in place. This won't be quick, as a rule. A portable electric room heater with appropriate safeguards left to run for a while should be fine, or even a fan blowing air on the section of wall with the house heat turned up. Don't get creative with fuel-based heat sources and asphyxiate yourself.

If it's a shower-only, there isn't much more you can do, practically speaking - if shower & tub then running water to the tub may help bring heat into the wall cavity, but with PEX it's not going to move along the pipes much (but at least it's less likely to burst, as well.)

Fixing this so it doesn't happen again would be a lot of work, so I doubt you'll want to if the temperature in question is unusual for the area. Letting it run a trickle in extremely cold weather is one coping mechanism that does not require rebuilding your house to cold climate standards (we try to avoid pipes in exterior walls, among other things.)

Comment: Second time I've seen this "run a trickle" advice is as many days. Your water pipes (should) be in a warm run. Your drainage not necessarily. Dripping tap in freezing drain = blocked drain = wet floor. I've seen it done.

Comment: Should, schmud. We are clearly dealing with "not properly built for actual climate conditions that can occur" - since "rebuilding the house to proper cold-climate standards right now" is not a practical option, run a trickle (not drip) helps keep it clear. Too slow can allow ice build up, so don't "drip."

Comment: I agree I have lived in a costal region that rarely freezes but every few years we get into the -F ranges, leaving cabinet doors open at the kitchen sink and  a faucet trickling in a bathroom prevent lots of problems. Note every faucet in this home is on an exterior wall it’s made it 91 years. I doubt we will be changing things any time soon.